# The sum of a struct within an array

Tags: struct, coldfusion

I am in the process of putting together a shopping cart, I am holding the cart data in an array, inside the array is a struct which holds the individual product information. I need get the sum of the totalprice column within the struct, please see my dump below, I have tried

`<cfset carTotal = ArraySum(session.mycart[ "totalPrice" ])>` but this creates an error

> the value totalprice cannot be converted to a number

Is this because I am using `arraysum` in a struct?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

[image: Shopping Cart Array]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `mycart` was a Query object, it'd be a simple `ArraySum(mycart.totalPrice)`

Since it's an array of struct, you've got to loop it yourself, which is still rather easy:

```
<cfset sum = 0>
<cfloop array="#session.mycart#" index="item">
    <cfset sum += item.totalPrice>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#sum#">
```

Don't forget to use `PrecisionEvaluate()` when you need full precision.

Comment: Thanks Henry! I am still amazed at the speed this forum works! It worked perfectly - thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As it's an array you'll have to loop yourself, keeping track of the sum.

```
<cfset cartTotal = 0 />

<cfloop array=#session.mycart# index="i">
    <cfset cartTotal += i.totalPrice /> 
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#cartTotal#" />
```

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks for your response, Henry just nipped in before you this time, but thank you for your efforts!!! both your replies work!

Comment: @Jason - If you found Barry's response helpful too, you can always upvote it as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Coldfusion 10 or Railo 4, you could use the [reduce function](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/#reduce) of [Underscore.cfc](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/):

```
_ = new Underscore();

cartTotal = _.reduce(session.mycart, function(total, item){
   return total + item.TotalPrice;
}, 0);
```

[reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) is a common higher-order function that "reduces" a set of values to a single value. In this case, we're "reducing" the price of all items in a collection to a single sum.

Using a well-understood function like`reduce`, rather than a custom solution, yields more readable code.

Note: I wrote Underscore.cfc

Answer (score 2):

Additional to the answer by Russ, in Coldfusion 11 or Lucee you can simply do `arrayReduce()` as well. No explicit need for underscore anymore.

```
cartTotal = arrayReduce(session.mycart, function(total, item){
   return total + item.TotalPrice;
}, 0);
```